# Mocking behavior of mysqli bind_result

Tags: php, unit-testing, mysqli, phpunit

We are trying to add Unit Testing to an existing application. We are willing to do refactoring to some extent, but there is an issue with the binding of variables.

Basically we use extensively the binding of PHP variables to mysqli results using mysqli's [bind_result](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) method.

The question is: there is a way we can mock that behavior? I mean, writing variables directly to the context of the method.

The other choice is write a wrapper around mysqli and change every method call, but we are trying to avoid it because it's too much work to be done in the given timeframe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what I was thinking about, I forgot about parameters by reference. I will have to write a specific mock for this class, but it should work.

```
class mysqli_stmt_mock {

      private $references = array();

      public function bind_result(&$var){
         $this->references[] = &$var;
      }

      public function writeOnReferences(){
          foreach($this->references as &$ref){
          $ref = 'test_string1';
       }
    }
}

$test = new mysqli_stmt_mock();

$var1 = 'foo';
$var2 = 'foo2';

$test->bind_result($var1);
$test->bind_result($var2);

print_r($var1);
print_r($var2);

$test->writeOnReferences();

print_r($var1);
print_r($var2);
```